# How to get iPhone-style overscrolling in Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)?

Tags: android, user-interface

In the stock Gingerbread release, overscrolling is indicated with an orange "flash". However, the release notes and some of the API docs seem to indicate that there is support for iPhone-style overshoot overscroll behavior. For example, see
[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollHeader(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)). However, it's not clear how to make these work. Simply setting drawables with these methods does not change the behavior. Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently did a couple of blog posts about this. Have a look!

https://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-overscroll-what/

https://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-overscroll-revisited/

Since then I've had a thought, when you override the overScrollBy method, I'm guessing that you can half one of those parameters to get the view to not follow your finger when you overscroll, but just follow half the distance.

Comment: is there a way to do this in android version < 2.3

Comment: In this implementation when the listview is overscrolled and you keep touching it, it bounces back without untouch it, which I want to avoid. Do you have any idea about how to do this?

Comment: Exactly, every update makes the `ScrollView` return to the original position despite the fact it's overscrolled or not.

Comment: How would you add this to a listView, and also have the effect of an ImageView being zoomed, like on this library:  https://github.com/ideaismobile/AKParallax-Android (sample : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appkraft.parallax_sample ) ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer this from experience, but under AbsListView, there is a method called [`setOverScrollMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29) that may be helpful. Beside that, however, I also found the [`OverScroller`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/OverScroller.html) class. This seems to be more what you're looking for; the details of implementation, I can't really help with, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've looked at those methods, but they don't help. The "overScrollMode" is on by default, so that method only allows it to be turned off. Turning it off just prevents the orange flash from appearing. The OverScroller class appears to manage the notification of overscroll behavior, but is not responsible for any rendering itself.

Comment: Looking into it further, I'm actually nearly positive that OverScroller handles the actual mechanics of overscrolling. The downside that I just realized, is that it is Android 2.3+ only (Gingerbread). It's been added to the ScrollView class, you can see some of the commits here: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=history;f=core/java/android/widget/ScrollView.java

Comment: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/OverScroller.java;h=f48eb89e596c52e09186941501284fc64a08db56;hb=737e8fe2c7ce167bc68ad779160488007a5e0b1d Here's the actual OverScroll code if you're interested. Scroll down to the MagneticOverScroller class to see the math behind it. (And I was wrong, they pulled it out as a separate class from ScrollView, it looks like)